# How to pass the parameters in to SSRS reports from Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I'm trying to pass the parameters in to SSRS report from coldfusion.. see the below code before i used to pass parameters in to crystal report.

```
<CFOUTPUT>
 <FORM NAME="MoveInSummaryByHouseReport"  action="//#crserver#/reports/MoveInSummaryByHouse.rpt" method="POST" TARGET="MoveInSummaryByHouseReport">
 <input type=hidden name="user0" value="#User#">
 <input type=hidden name="password0" value="#Password#">
 <INPUT TYPE="Hidden" name="prompt0" value="#HouseData.cName#">
   <INPUT TYPE="Hidden" NAME="prompt1" VALUE="#form.prompt1#">  
</FORM>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

But now i have to pass same parameters in to SSRS report instead of crystal report..
I tried below passing **prompt0/prompt1** parameters coming from above code.. It's not working. 
SSRS url: http://vmdbprod02dev.alcco.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTIPS4%2fMove-Ins+Summary+By+House&rc:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&Scope=House&Selection=**prompt0**&Period=**prompt1**&ResidencyType=0

How can i pass the parameters in to SSRS report.. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: I have some legacy code that calls SSRS from CF. It looks similar to what you have so, sorry if it isn't any help. The call looks like `http://reportServer/reportName&ID=#ID#&rs:format=PDF&rs:ClearSession=true`. *Note* the reportName does not have a file extension.

Answer (score 0):

We have a page that does that.  The ColdFusion page does whatever it needs to do and then does a cflocation to an asp page that includes the ssrs report.  The ColdFusion variables are passed as url variables.